# Web api (.Net Core) returning 204 No content after publish

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have sample .net core web api application in which wrote different actions. That actions are returning the data that i want to return but after publishing the same web api application, it is returning 204 No Content.

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("GetProducts/{Id}")]
 public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Mart_Model.ProductStock>> GetProducts(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var Products = _repository.GetProducts(id);
                return Ok(Products);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                return BadRequest(new Response { Status = "Error", Message = ex.ToString() }); 
            }
            
        }
```

this Api route is returning me list of data when i am sending request by running the application thought the Visual Studio it's returning me list or Product (That is Correct).
Like:
http://localhost:49774/api/martController/GetProducts/0

But when i hit the same rout after publish the Web api Application on iis it's returning me **204 No Content** (That is Wrong)
Like url: http://localhost/DailyMart/api/martController/GetProducts/0

i named my application on iis **DailyMart**

Please help me figure that out.

Comment: Where you store your products?

Comment: have you tried testing the other endpoints? that response looks like returned by IIS, not your web app.

Comment: ..l./GetProducts/0 I think that just there are no products for Id=0

Answer (score 0):

`return Ok(Products);` will fetch you `http 204` only if `Products` is `null`.

```
return Ok((IEnumerable<Mart_Model.ProductStock>)null); // <-- gets you 204
```

If the `_repository.GetProducts(id);` returns non-materialized `IEnumerable<T>` that is not `null` and you will get `200` even if no records returned in the empty collection.

Hence you need to find, how do you get the `null`

You should also [read this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Feb/24/Null-API-Responses-and-HTTP-204-Results-in-ASPNET-Core)